# Is there a function $f(n)$ satisfying some constraints?

Tags: functional-analysis, special-functions

If there a function $f(x)$ such that following three conditions can be satisfied?
$$\bigg(\frac{f\big(x^{c(x)}\big)}{\log f\big(x^{c(x)}\big)}\bigg)^{\log f(x^{c(x)})}= c(x)(\log x) x^{c(x)}$$ 
$$c(x)=\frac{\log f(x^{c(x)})}{2 f(x^{c(x)})-\log f(x^{c(x)})}$$
$$1\leq\log f\big(x^{c(x)}\big)<f\big(x^{c(x)}\big)\leq\frac{({{1+c(x)}})\log x}{4\log(1+c(x))-4\log2+4\log\log x}$$

where $c(x)$ is given by:
$$0<c(x)\leq\frac{\log\log x}{(\log x)^\beta}$$
 at some $\beta\in(0,1)$.

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut everything I can. I think it does not exist but not 100% sure.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? What exactly have you tried?

Comment: I tried several candidate functions for $f$ such has $\log x$, $e^{(\log x)^\gamma},e^{(\log\log x)^{1/\gamma}}$ at $\gamma\in(0,1)$ and so on.

Comment: OK. What is the context?

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut a very strange optimization problem that I cannot reveal because of confidentiality reasons.

Comment: If you have confidentiality agreements, why are you posting on math.stackexchange?

Comment: This is a oblivious case. Does not reveal the intend of the problem.

Comment: Fine. Do you know the inverse of $f(x) = x^2-x\log x$?

Comment: Is that the solution??

Comment: Not entirely. It's related to the first one.

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut I did not know that. But its does not seem to satisfy other constraints. Am I right? So there is no hope?

Comment: No. Let me write up what I have.

Comment: What is the domain of $f$? And is $c$ continuous? Is $c$ monotonically increasing (please say yes)?

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut $f$ takes arguments in $\Bbb R_+$ and $c$ is monotonic yes (infact the upper bounds on c are monotonic as you notice). Good news?

Comment: Good news as in I can solve the problem. There may or may not be a solution. Edit: A couple more things: does there necessarily exist an $x$ given $n$ such that $c(x)>n$ (i.e. is it unbounded)? And is $f$ smooth?

Comment: The only thing I would like $f$ to be is that it satisfies $f(x)<\frac{\log x}{2\log\log x}$. $c(x)\in(0,1)$ as can be seen from the bounds on $c(x)$. I think any solution for $f(x)$ would be smooth.

Comment: but even with unbounded $c(x)$ say if $\beta=10^{-9}$ and $c(x)=\beta\log\log x$ I would be interested (this is a secondary and marginally imporant $c(x)$ for me in case the first formulation has no possibility).

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut is there any hope?

Answer (score 1):

Partial Solution - I'm almost done, but it looks like you're getting antsy, so here's what I have so far.

Look at the first condition. Note that this is entirely a function of $x^{c(x)}$.

Let $x^{c(x)} = g(x)$. The condition then becomes

$$\left(\frac{f(g(x))}{\log f(g(x))}\right)^{\log f(g(x))} = g(x)\log(g(x))$$

Letting $u=g(x)$:

$$\left(\frac{f(u)}{\log f(u)}\right)^{\log f(u)} = u\log u$$

Taking $\log$ of each side:

$$(\log f(u))^2-(\log f(u))(\log\log f(u)) = \log u - \log\log u$$

Define

$$h(a) = a^2-a\log a$$

So, we then get that, for all $u$ in the image of $x^{c(x)}$,

$f(u) = \exp(h^{-1}(\log u-\log\log u))$

Since we only care about the value of $f$ at $x^{c(x)}$, we can assume that

$$f\left(x^{c(x)}\right) = \exp\bigg(h^{-1}\big((c(x)\log x) - (\log c(x)) - (\log\log x)\big)\bigg)$$

We now have our function $f\left(x^{c(x)}\right)$, and all that remains is to see whether it satisfies the other properties. We have

$$c(x) = \frac{\log f(u)}{2f(u)-\log f(u)}$$

using the same $u$ as before. Solving for $f(u)$ in terms of $c(x)$:

$$2f(u)c(x) - c(x)(\log f(u)) = \log f(u)$$

$$\frac{2c(x)}{c(x)+1}f(u) = \log f(u)$$

Letting $a = \frac{2c(x)}{c(x)+1}$:

$$af(u) = \log f(u)$$

$$e^{af(u)} = f(u)$$

$$-ae^{af(u)} = -af(u)$$

$$-a = (-af(u))e^{(-af(u))}$$

Using the Lambert W function defined as the inverse of $h(x) = xe^x$:

$$-af(u) = W(-a)$$

$$f(u) = \frac{W(-a)}{-a}$$

$$f\left(x^{c(x)}\right) = -\frac{W\left(-\frac{2c(x)}{c(x)+1}\right)}{\frac{2c(x)}{c(x)+1}}$$

But we have from before that

$$f\left(x^{c(x)}\right) = \exp\bigg(h^{-1}\big((c(x)\log x) - (\log c(x)) - (\log\log x)\big)\bigg)$$

so, for a solution to exist, we must have that

$$-\frac{(c(x)+1)W\left(-\frac{2c(x)}{c(x)+1}\right)}{2c(x)} = \exp\bigg(h^{-1}\big((c(x)\log x) - (\log c(x)) - (\log\log x)\big)\bigg)$$

$$\log(c(x)+1)-\log(c(x))-\log(2)+\log\left(-W\left(-\frac{2c(x)}{c(x)+1}\right)\right) = h^{-1}\big((c(x)\log x) - (\log c(x)) - (\log\log x)\big)$$

$$h\left(\log(c(x)+1)-\log(c(x))-\log(2)+\log\left(-W\left(-\frac{2c(x)}{c(x)+1}\right)\right)\right) = (c(x)\log x) - (\log c(x)) - (\log\log x)$$

By the definition of $h$:

$$\left(\log(c(x)+1)-\log(c(x))-\log(2)+\log\left(-W\left(-\frac{2c(x)}{c(x)+1}\right)\right)\right)^2-\left(\log(c(x)+1)-\log(c(x))-\log(2)+\log\left(-W\left(-\frac{2c(x)}{c(x)+1}\right)\right)\right)\log\left(\log(c(x)+1)-\log(c(x))-\log(2)+\log\left(-W\left(-\frac{2c(x)}{c(x)+1}\right)\right)\right)= (c(x)\log x) - (\log c(x)) - (\log\log x)$$

Comment: $W(-2)\in\Bbb C$

Comment: @Turbo Sure, but our argument of $W$ is between $-1$ and $0$.

Comment: interestinggggg but $W(-0.5)\in\Bbb C$ as well.

Comment: @Turbo This is the ugliest mess I've ever seen...

Comment: yes I totally understand.... may be there is nothing ( but may be for $c(x)=\beta\log\log x$ there is possibility at $\beta\in(0,10^{-9})$)?

Comment: @Turbo Do you have any ideas about what can be done from here? I'm guessing there's a specific function $c$ for which this works, but it is very unlikely to hold in the general case.

Comment: I think $\beta\log\log x$ has a chance. The function I posted has no chance I think.

Comment: @Turbo Do you mean $c(x) = \frac{\log\log x}{(\log x)^{\beta}}$? Do you have specific functions, or would you like the general case? I'm almost sure there is a function $c$ that satisfies this, but it's probably really really ugly.

Comment: No I mean $c(x)=\beta \log\log x$ may have a chance. What is the asymptote you get for $c(x)$?

Comment: @Turbo I'm not sure I follow. What do you mean by "the asymptote I get for $c(x)$"? Everything I've done I've posted.

Comment: sorry I was thinking something else. It is clear from your analysis there is no $c(x)$ not even constant function.

Comment: @Turbo Why is that clear? I don't see it.

Comment: because W function evaluates to complex number while RHS is real.

Comment: @Turbo As long as $\frac{2c}{c+1}<\frac{1}{e}$, or equivalently $c(x)<\frac{1}{2e-1}$, it works just fine. $c$ has to satisfy this for all $x$, but it still could work. I'll get back to this in the morning.

Comment: I do not understand. If what you claim is true it is very interesting for me.

Comment: I only see $W(-\frac{2c}{c+1})$ which has negative argument.

Comment: @Turbo but $W(-x)$ is defined if $x\leq\frac{1}{e}$.

Comment: ok thank you interesting that there is a way.

Comment: any luck with this?